# How to change background color and color of textbloxk content of selected item of a listbox in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

am working on Windows phone 8 app. I am using a listbox to display a list dynamically and on selection change for an item in listbox i want selected item backgroung color to be blue and textblock text color to be white(only for the selected item)
This is my xaml code for listbox

```
<Canvas  x:Name="Canvas_Main" Margin="23,191,27,75" Tap="Canvas_Main_Tap">
        <ListBox x:Name="Listbox_Main" Height="534" Width="430" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged" Tap="Listbox_Main_Tap" Canvas.Left="10"  >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas x:Name="cnv_Items" Height="100" Width="200">
                        <Border Height="100" Width="200" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFD0D0D0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb_Value" Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="26" Height="40" Width="195" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="2"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb_UnitName" Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="19" Height="40" Width="180" Canvas.Top="55" Canvas.Left="10"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
```

Its my Code Behind :-

```
private void Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Canvas_KeyBoard.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                OutAnimation();
            if (Listbox_Main.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                myitem = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)Listbox_Main.SelectedItem;
                ListBoxItem myitem1 = Listbox_Main.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                myitem1.Background = brush;
                Conversion_Logic();
            }

        }
```

Please tell me what to do, i am working on this issue for 2 days but unable to get the solution. Hope u guyz help me

Comment: You need to change background et color for SelectedState. Use Blend for do this, it's really easy :)

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493221/listboxitem-stop-showing-highlited-on-select-in-windows-phone-8/23495244#23495244

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a selectionchanged event For your ListBox, you could try this. Best solution would be using styles and triggers

```
    private void Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem myitem = Listbox_Main.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
        SolidColorBrush brush =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));
        myitem.Background = brush;
    }
```

Comment: private void Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (Listbox_Main.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                myitem = (KeyValuePair<string,  string>)Listbox_Main.SelectedItem;
                ListBoxItem myitem1 = Listbox_Main.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                myitem1.Background = brush;
                Conversion_Logic();
            }
            
        }

Comment: @user3683525 It dint work? can you post complete code

Comment: Hi i have tried the above code which you have given but myitem is showing null value here.

Comment: do you have items inside your List?

Comment: yes, i am getting the items using single data template.

ListBoxItem myitem1 = Listbox_Main.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem; here on debugging, SelectedItem is showing item but myitem1 is still null

Comment: can you remove these two lines and debug,  if (Canvas_KeyBoard.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                OutAnimation();

Comment: I have removed that and tried, still the result is same.

Comment: myitem1 Comes as null?

Comment: Then problem lies where you bind the Listbox